# CF Getting the sum of a column on a database query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to calculate the total of a column using ColdFusion and MS Sql.

Will someone please tell me what I am overlooking? My total for the location total is not doing the sum of the column but for somereason just taking the last number in that column. Where am I going wrong?

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT *
        FROM cl_checklists
    </cfquery>

    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry> 

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Percent of Total Checklists</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location Total</strong></th> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount FROM GetLocationInfo GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location 
    </cfquery>
     <cfloop query="allLocCode">
      <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />

      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>
        <cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCodeForLocationQry['locCntr'])>
      <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
        <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/allLocCode.locationCount) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
        <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
      </tr>
     </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><cfoutput>#numberFormat(columnSum)#</cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--- Total of All Sum of each column --->
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you know how to use COUNT() in SQL ... have you tried SUM() ?

Comment: I think maybe I was looking at this the wrong way. My first instinct is always to perform math and alter data in the query itself before using ColdFusion variables but that isn't prudent here. Check out my answer below - I think it'll work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `columnSum` variable is inside your `cfloop`.  Put the `<cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCodeForLocationQry['locCntr'])>` line outside of the `cfloop` (either before or after), and you should get your grand total of `334`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Each time you loop through the query, append a value (the count of locations) to a list.

Something like this:

```
<cfset myList = "">
<cfloop query="allLocCode">
<cfset myList = ListAppend(myList, locationCount, ',')>

<!---your other logic--->
</cfloop>
```

At the end of your loop you should have a list of numbers as long as your query's recordcount.

You can add up all those numbers using this old function I found on CFLib.

```
<cfscript>
function listSum(listStr)
{
  var delim = ",";
  if(ArrayLen(Arguments) GTE 2) 
    delim = Arguments[2];
  return ArraySum(ListToArray(listStr, delim));
}
</cfscript>
```

So, for example, if your final list was called `myList` and had values such as `14, 100, 7` - you would write out:

```
<cfoutput>#listSum(myList)#</cfoutput>
```

And get your final answer of `121`.

Comment: If you need to keep a list put it in an array and convert to a list later. Much more performant.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Good catch. I was tired and just trying to piece together the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is sql server, why not take advantage of its ability to use the `with` keyword?  The general idea is this:

```
with totalRecords as 
(select count(*) records
from etc),

groupedRecords as
(select someField, count(*) recordsForField
from etc
group by someField)

select whatevever
, (groupedRecords.recordsForField / totalRecords.records) * 100 percentage
from someTables
join groupedRecords on groupedRecords.someField = someTable.someField

where totalRecords.records > 0
```

Then you simply output your query results.